# How to show controller or model with all decorators applied from gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, spree

Is there a way to show the complete decorated controller/model in one file? For example, I have a controller that is being decorated with many gems I've installed and I would like to see the complete finished code in one view.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do that. You will have to look into each gem for changes/updates in controller/model.